# From XML to PHP to Array to JSON Object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

As the title says, I got a Xml file and reading the values in php and saves them in an array. My array works perfectly in PHP.

I can return my values one by one just by taking them from the array:

```
echo myArray[0][1];
```

Which will return: text

This is a var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[13]
          string 'text' (length=47)
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[14]
          string 'lol' (length=22)
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[15]
          string 'hehe' (length=8)
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
          string 'thanks' (length=4)
      4 => null
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[17]
          string 'texxtttttttt' (length=34)
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[18]
          string 'text here' (length=16)
      2 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
          string 'alots of text i guess' (length=44)
      3 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[20]
          string 'some more text' (length=23)
      4 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[21]
          string 'some text here' (length=14)
```

Now to the problem.

```
var obj= <?php print json_encode($myArray); ?>;
```

I can't get the values one by one anymore. I've tried to loop it and put the values in an Array again

```
            var questions = new Array();
            $.each(obj , function(k, v) {  
                    $.each(v, function(k2, v2) {
                        $.each(v2, function(k3, v3) {
                              questions[k2] = v3;
                        });       
                    });
                });
```

This doesn't give me the result that I want.
What I need is to save the values one by one like i did in the array in php ( myArray[0][1]; ) 
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to write PHP Code into a Javascript file? I heavily discourage that.
Split your code into a PHP only file that does nothing except json-encoding your array:

```
<?php print json_encode($myArray); ?>;
```

In your JS-File you start an ajax request to get the string from your PHP file. jQuery has [convenient methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for exactly that:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )
```

Here's another resource that shows more complex alternatives:
[Ajax Query to get JSON](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/)

Comment: Actually fixed it by changing the each function to: $.each(obj, function(k, v) {  
 document.write(v[0][0] + "<br>")
 document.write(v[1][0] + "<br>")
 document.write(v[2][0] + "<br>")
 document.write(v[3][0] + "<br>")
 if(v[4])
  document.write(v[4][0] + "<br>")     
});